# FBSession Must Be Specified Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am trying to follow the Parse tutorial for Logging in With Facebook.  However, the sample code does not match up with the guide, so the code there is useless.  I have followed the guide completely, but after I login, it directs me to Facebook app, I give permission, it goes back to the app I am building, but I get the following error

`FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint 'me': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.`

What is going on?  In Login controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // handle successful response
        } else if ([[[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"] objectForKey:@"type"]
                    isEqualToString: @"OAuthException"]) { // Since the request failed, we can check if it was due to an invalid session
            NSLog(@"The facebook session was invalidated");
            [self logoutButtonAction:nil];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Some other error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
    if ([PFUser currentUser] && // Check if user is cached
        [PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) { // Check if user is linked to Facebook
        // Present the next view controller without animation
        [self _presentUserDetailsViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
- (IBAction)loginButtonTouchHandler:(id)sender  {
    // Set permissions required from the facebook user account
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        [_activityIndicator stopAnimating]; // Hide loading indicator

        if (!user) {
            NSString *errorMessage = nil;
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                errorMessage = @"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.";
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
                errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
            }
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error"
                                                            message:errorMessage
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
            [alert show];
        } else {
            if (user.isNew) {
                NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
            }
            [self _presentUserDetailsViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }];

    [_activityIndicator startAnimating]; // Show loading indicator until login is finished
}

- (void)_presentUserDetailsViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    UserDetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[UserDetailsViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
}
```

In my UserDetailsViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // ...
    [self _loadData];
}

- (void)_loadData {
    // ...
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
            NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;

            NSString *facebookID = userData[@"id"];
            NSString *name = userData[@"name"];
            NSString *location = userData[@"location"][@"name"];
            NSString *gender = userData[@"gender"];
            NSString *birthday = userData[@"birthday"];
            NSString *relationship = userData[@"relationship_status"];

            NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];
            // URL should point to https://graph.facebook.com/{facebookId}/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1
                       NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pictureURL];

            // Run network request asynchronously
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   completionHandler:
             ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                 if (connectionError == nil && data != nil) {
                     // Set the image in the header imageView
                     self.headerImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                 }
             }];

            // Now add the data to the UI elements
            // ...
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: Two questions: One, where are you seeing the error? (I'm assuming via alert in your login callback since you describe that this occurs after returning from Facebook) Two, do you call [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook] in your appDelegate on application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:? That call should initialize the session as well I believe. - Whoops, just saw the initialize in your method, I'd still suggest moving it to the app delegate though

Comment: One other idea for you could be if the user is cached. Perhaps logging out and trying again would help. Since you don't initializeFacebook until pressing the login button, if a user is cached and you transition to the next screen, you might be trying to requestForMe before initializing Facebook. This could throw the error that there is no open session.

Comment: I will try moving that to the app delegate.  I didn't  put it there because I was just simply following the tutorial, and put it where they said to.  Silly me for thinking a company could get their own tutorial right.

Comment: Haha, let me know if that works. I'm not sure if its an issue with caching a residual login or not, but it looks like trying to log in a cached user is occurring before initializing Facebook, which would be a problem. If you never got past the first login, then that wouldn't be the case, but if so then it's possible!

Comment: That was the issue.  Glad it was a mistake in their guide and not something I did.

Comment: Good to hear! I'll post an answer in case anybody else stumbles across this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out, when trying to create an auto-login feature with this function:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // handle successful response
        } else if ([[[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"] objectForKey:@"type"]
                isEqualToString: @"OAuthException"]) { // Since the request failed, we can check if it was due to an invalid session
            NSLog(@"The facebook session was invalidated");
            [self logoutButtonAction:nil];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Some other error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
    if ([PFUser currentUser] && // Check if user is cached
        [PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) { // Check if user is linked to Facebook
        // Present the next view controller without animation
        [self _presentUserDetailsViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

We actually end up skipping the **[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook]** call, since it only happens when you push the login button. The solution is to **put this call in the appDelegate** in the method *application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*